# Implement generic objects comparing in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm implementing generic objects comparing method to compare instances of classes in my project. In each class I have some value type variable and some bindinglist of its associate class. With value type variable, I can use `==` operator or `equal` operator to compare it, but with bindinglist, I don't know how to cast it to `bindinglist<type of associate class>` to iterate through it and perform recursion.

```
public bool IsEqual<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
{
    PropertyInfo[] prop1 = obj1.GetType().GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo[] prop2 = obj2.GetType().GetProperties(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < prop1.Count; i++)
    {
        if(prop1[i].IsValueType && prop2[i].IsValueType)
        {
            if(prop1.GetValue(i) != prop2.GetValue(i))
                return false
        }
        else
        {
            //This is bindinglist of associate class
            //I need to cast it to iterate in perform recursion here            
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

So how can I implement recursion when property is a bindinglist?

P/S: forgive my bad English

**UPDATE:**

After consider carefully, I implemented `IEqualtable` as Mr. Stephen Hewlett suggested. Thank you very much, Mr. Stephen Hewlett. And for those who still want to use compare function, I'll give you an approach that I think it will work:

```
public bool IsEqual(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
    PropertyInfo[] prop1 = obj1.GetType().GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo[] prop2 = obj2.GetType().GetProperties(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < prop1.Count; i++)
    {
        if(prop1[i].IsValueType && prop2[i].IsValueType)
        {
            if(prop1[i].GetValue(obj1, null) != prop2[i].GetValue(obj2, null))
                return false;
        }
        else if (prop1[i].PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop2[i].PropertyType.IsGenericType) //if property is a generic list
        {
            //Get actual type of property
            Type type = prop1[i].PropertyType;

            //Cast property into type
            var list1 = Convert.ChangeType(prop1[i].GetValue(obj1, null), type);
            var list2 = Convert.ChangeType(prop1[i].GetValue(obj2, null), type);

            if (list1.count != list2.count)
                return false;

            for j as integer = 0 to list1.Count - 1
            {
                //Recursion here
                if (!IsEqual(list1(j), list2(j)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else //if property is instance of a class
        {
            Type type = prop1[i].PropertyType;
            Object object1 = Convert.ChangeType(prop1[i].GetValue(obj1, null), type);
            Object object2 = Convert.ChangeType(prop1[i].GetValue(obj2, null), type);

            //Recursion
            if(!IsEqual(object1, object2))
            {
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want the code to do?

Comment: At the else phrase, `prop1[i]` and `prop2[i]` is a bindinglist of associate class. EX: obj1 and obj2 is instance of Foo, and both obj1 and obj2 include a binding list of Bar. So at the else phrase I need to cast `prop1[i]` and `prop2[i]` to `BindingList<Bar>` or any type that I can iterate through it and perform recursion

Comment: I'm not sure you need to use reflection at all to do this... what is the overall aim of the method? What types will be passed into it?

Comment: This method will compare 2 instances of a class and see if they equal or not.

Comment: OK, what classes? Any classes at all, or just some specific ones?

Comment: Any classes that I defined in my project so that I want to make it generic by using reflection. And I don't want to implement `IEqualtable` or `IComparable` because I have to modify all my classes in that case

Comment: It's not really possible to do that. Equality means different things for different classes. There is an IEquatable<T> interface in .NET that many of the .NET base classes implement which I think already allows you to do what you are trying to do - by allowing each individual class to define how two instances are compared.

Comment: So it will only be to compare classes that you have written as part of this project?

Comment: Yes, only those classes. And as I commented earlier, I'm trying to avoid using `IEqualtable` or `IComparable` because I have to modify my classes, and there's a lots of classes in my project

Comment: I see. One last question... by recursion, do you mean that if the type of a property is one of your classes, that you then want to call the IsEqual method again but passing in the two instances of the property, to check that those values are equal too?

Comment: Actually it's a 1bindinglist1 and Yes, that what I mean by recursion, and the problem I'm facing is that I can't cast it to `bindinglist<bar> as the example of #2 comment

Comment: Firstly, this code is not Generic, therefore there is no need to cast to `IEnumerable<TChild>` to then invoke `IsEqual()` on each child. Each of the methods you use in `IsEqual` could equally work on `System.Object`. Secondly, usage of generics in reflection is not very nice. Thirdly, given the signature of the method, it looks like you intend to use it everywhere as library code, hence I would HIGHLY advise against reflection, as it is extremely slow compared to inlined code.

Comment: I would advise you to use `IEqualityComparer` instead if you prefer not to modify your classes. If need be, use code generation/IL generation/Expression trees/anything except reflection for implementing the `IEqualityComparer`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *very very strongly* recommend implementing IEquatable for all your classes - nomatter how many of them there are - as using reflection for something that does not need it is usually a bad idea. A fundamental advantage of C# is the type safety you get by using all the built in type features. By using reflection you are trying to imitate what C# and .NET does for you already, and you will probably get it wrong.

Your method does not need to be generic as it is using reflection, so the objects in question will be passed to the reflection methods as `object` anyway. There is no advantage to adding the type parameter. Without the type parameter it will be easier for you to cast the binding list as you need to.

Comment: I got it, thank for your time and your suggestion. Have a nice day, Mr. Stephen Hewlett :)

Comment: A valid alternative to `IEquatable` is to use `IEqualityComparer` as an external class. However, I agree that I would strongly recommend you implementing `IEquatable` if possible. If you want to reduce the amount of code you write, you could generate the IEquatable code at compile time.